# Minimize cost based on purchased volume Pyomo

Tags: optimization, pyomo

I'd like to find the optimal solution for buying goods from suppliers where the shipping cost is dependent on the cost of goods bought from given supplier. I'm using Pyomo. My code so far is:

```
model = ConcreteModel(name="(MN_2)")

# products
N = ['prod1', 'prod2', 'prod3']

# suppliers
M = ['A', 'B']

# price
p = {('prod1', 'A'): 10,
     ('prod2', 'A'): 9,
     ('prod3', 'A'): 50,
     ('prod1', 'B'): 16,
     ('prod2', 'B'): 20,
     ('prod3', 'B'): 35}

# user quantity contraint
q_u = {('prod1', 'A'): 2,
     ('prod2', 'A'): 1,
     ('prod3', 'A'): 1,
     ('prod1', 'B'): 1,
     ('prod2', 'B'): 1,
     ('prod3', 'B'): 1}

# seller quantity contraint
q_s = {('prod1', 'A'): 20,
     ('prod2', 'A'): 10,
     ('prod3', 'A'): 10,
     ('prod1', 'B'): 10,
     ('prod2', 'B'): 10,
     ('prod3', 'B'): 10}


# quantity of product n bough in shop m
model.x = Var(N, M, bounds=(0,10))

def obj_rule(model):
    return sum(p[n,m]*model.x[n,m] for n in N for m in M)
model.obj = Objective(rule=obj_rule)

def user_quantity(model, n, m):
    return model.x[n,m] >= q_u[n,m]
model.user_quantity = Constraint(N, M, rule=user_quantity)

def seller_quantity(model, n, m):
    return model.x[n,m] <= q_s[n,m]
model.seller_quantity = Constraint(N, M, rule=seller_quantity)

solver = SolverFactory('glpk')
solver.solve(model)
model.x.pprint()
```

What I'm struggling with is how to include the shipping cost that is dependent on the cost of goods bought from given supplier. For example:

For supplier A: shipping cost is =

- 10 if the sum of costs of products bought from them is <= 100,
- 0 if the sum of costs of products bought from them is > 100

For supplier B: shipping cost is =

- 8 if the sum of costs of products bought from them is <= 150,
- 0 if the sum of costs of products bought from them is > 150

Comment: You additional costs seem to have two possible values each. Mathematically, how would you model/keep track of whether the sum cost exceeds the threshold?

Comment: I'd say for example for A: shipping_cost = {10 for model.x[n,m] * p[n,m] <= 100, 0 for   model.x[n,m] * p[n,m] < 100.

Comment: You can't directly use that logical statement in your integer program because it isn't a linear function. What you're looking for is an implementation of an if-else constraint using binary variables. (Here)[https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2500415] is a good mathematical explanation of the concept. You can add a binary variable for each supplier and corresponding constraints that makes the variables 1 if the sum of costs meets the threshold. Then you can multiply that variable by the cost

Comment: Why is the assumption that this should be formulated as linear problem?

Comment: Sorry, I was loose with my use of linear in this case. I just meant that your definition of the shipping cost in the comment doesn't directly translate to implementation in  a (mixed-integer) linear programming model. But the if-else formulation of the constraints using binary variables does.

Comment: Right. But the model doesn't have to be a (mixed-integer) linear programming model. If I'm nit wrong, Pyomo can handle non-linear optimization, I just don't know how and was seeking some help with that. But thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

The constraints you're describing are an implementation of if-then condition which is described [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/33/4634). The quirk is that your conditions require the binary variable to be 1 if your procurement costs are less than or equal to some threshold rather than strictly less than the threshold. We can add a very small number (0.0001) to the threshold that doesn't affect adherence to the condition and allow us to use the new value in a strictly less than inequality.

To your initial model, you can add one new binary variable per seller (`model.shipping_bin`) and one constraint per binary variable that forces the binary variable to be 1 if the cost is less than the threshold and 0 otherwise. We can then multiply by the shipping cost in the objective function by these variables.

```
# add new binary variables to track costs per supplier
model.shipping_bin = Var(M,within = Binary)
shipping_costs = {'A':10,'B':8}
shipping_thresholds = {'A':100,'B':150} # threshold to meet to not incur shipping

# We need big M values to multiply the binaries to enforce the constraint without constraining the procurement cost incurred.
# We can set to the maximum amount we expect to procure from the seller
# The largest cost you could incur from each seller is
# the price times the max quantity
shipping_big_m = {seller: sum([p[(prod,seller)] * q_s[(prod,seller)] for prod in N])
                  for seller in M}


# add constraints
def shipping_bin_rule(model,seller):
    # Sets shipping binary var to 1 if threshold not met
    # Allows it to be 0 otherwise
    # 790 * (model.shipping_bin['A']) >= 100.0001 + cost of products from seller 'A'
        # if cost of products from 'A' < 100.0001 then binary variable = 1
    # 710 * (model.shipping_bin['B']) >= 150.0001 + cost of products from seller 'B'
        # if cost of products from 'B' < 150.0001 then binary variable = 1
    epsilon = .0001 # to make sure case where cost == threshold is still accounted for
    return(shipping_big_m[seller] * model.shipping_bin[seller] >= shipping_thresholds[seller] + epsilon - sum([p[(product,seller)] * model.x[product,seller]
                                                                             for product in N]))

model.shipping_bin_con = Constraint(M,rule = shipping_bin_rule)

# new objective function adding the shipping cost
def obj_with_shipping_rule(model):
    orig_cost = obj_rule(model) # call the original function, but can combine into one function if desired
    # apply the shipping cost if cost of products is less than threshold (binary is 0)
    shipping_cost = sum([shipping_costs[seller] * model.shipping_bin[seller]
                         for seller in M])
    return(orig_cost + shipping_cost)

# deactivate the original objective to apply the new one
model.obj.deactivate()
model.obj_with_shipping = Objective(rule = obj_with_shipping_rule)


# solve the model with new obj
solver.solve(model)
model.x.pprint() # x values remain unchanged
# x : Size=6, Index=x_index
#     Key            : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
#     ('prod1', 'A') :     0 :   2.0 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
#     ('prod1', 'B') :     0 :   1.0 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
#     ('prod2', 'A') :     0 :   1.0 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
#     ('prod2', 'B') :     0 :   1.0 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
#     ('prod3', 'A') :     0 :   1.0 :    10 : False : False :  Reals
#     ('prod3', 'B') :     0 :   1.0 :    10 : False : False :  Reals

# cost from A = 2 * 10 + 1 * 9 + 1 * 50 = 79 < 100 so model.shipping_bin['A'] = 1
# cost from B = 1 * 16 + 1 * 20 + 1 * 35 = 71 < 150 so model.shipping_bin['B'] = 1
model.shipping_bin.pprint()
# shipping_bin : Size=2, Index=shipping_bin_index
#     Key : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
#       A :     0 :   1.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
#       B :     0 :   1.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
value(model.obj_with_shipping) # 168 (18 units larger than original because of shipping)
```